# multiple distinct from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

MySQL request is:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.field_department_color_value, DISTINCT a.nid,  DISTINCT c.nid, DISTINCT c.field_oeuvre_notice_bibliography_value, DISTINCT c.field_oeuvre_notice_author_value, DISTINCT d.field_oeuvre_cartel_dimension_value, DISTINCT d.field_oeuvre_cartel_origin_value

FROM (                
                SELECT DISTINCT field_department_color_value,nid
                                FROM content_type_department) a,

                (       SELECT field_oeuvre_notice_dep_value
                            FROM content_field_oeuvre_notice_dep) b,

                (       SELECT field_oeuvre_notice_bibliography_value, field_oeuvre_notice_author_value, field_oeuvre_notice_cartel_nid
                            FROM content_type_oeuvre_notice) c,

                 (      SELECT field_oeuvre_cartel_dimension_value, field_oeuvre_cartel_origin_value, nid
                            FROM content_type_oeuvre_cartel) d,



WHERE    a.nid = b.field_oeuvre_notice_dep_value
AND      d.nid = c.field_oeuvre_notice_cartel_nid
AND      a.field_department_color_value LIKE 'greek'
LIMIT 0 , 8
```

it takes distinct just for the attribute field_department_color_value! while I want to do it for all  the attributes in the SELECT section... Thank you

Comment: Try this `SELECT  DISTINCT col1,col2,col3....`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.field_department_color_value, 
a.nid,  
c.nid, 
c.field_oeuvre_notice_bibliography_value, 
c.field_oeuvre_notice_author_value, 
d.field_oeuvre_cartel_dimension_value, 
d.field_oeuvre_cartel_origin_value

FROM (                
                SELECT DISTINCT field_department_color_value,nid
                                FROM content_type_department) a,

                (       SELECT field_oeuvre_notice_dep_value
                            FROM content_field_oeuvre_notice_dep) b,

                (       SELECT field_oeuvre_notice_bibliography_value, field_oeuvre_notice_author_value, field_oeuvre_notice_cartel_nid
                            FROM content_type_oeuvre_notice) c,

                 (      SELECT field_oeuvre_cartel_dimension_value, field_oeuvre_cartel_origin_value, nid
                            FROM content_type_oeuvre_cartel) d,



WHERE    a.nid = b.field_oeuvre_notice_dep_value
AND      d.nid = c.field_oeuvre_notice_cartel_nid
AND      a.field_department_color_value LIKE 'greek'
LIMIT 0 , 8
```

Comment: still giving the same result. Takes Distinct just for 'field_department_color_value' et not for the others

Comment: Can you give an example of your data you have in the question and the expected result

Comment: I want to display the department, bibliography, author and cartel image of each work! by my request it displays me down results same for different departments!eben if i change this: AND      a.field_department_color_value LIKE 'greek' and i pu another department!